# When configuring update-notifier - cannot find chardet even though it is installed

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, python-2.7

So my ubuntu installation (16.04.6 LTS) is having a problem configuring the update-notifier:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.10) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 38, in <module>
    import chardet
ImportError: No module named 'chardet'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.168.10); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 ubuntu-desktop
```

So, it looks like I need chadet to have this configuration work.  Attempting to install this tells me it is already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-chardet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-chardet is already the newest version (2.3.0-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Not sure why python (v.2.7.12) cannot find chardet, any ideas?

Says it is installed for Python 3 as well:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-chardet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-chardet is already the newest version (2.3.0-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Comment: You need chardet for Python 3 here, not for 2. Try `sudo apt install python3-chardet` instead.

Comment: @ByteCommander - so it looks like I have that installed as well - so that doesn't seem to be the problem.   Python path problem maybe?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the problem.   After mucking around with it a bit, I found out that I have two different version of python3 (3.5 and 3.6) and python3 symbolic link in /usr/bin was pointing to the wrong one (3.5).   Deleted the link, re-generated to point to 3.6 - now things work:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.10) ...
Setting up update-notifier (3.168.10) ...
Setting up ubuntu-desktop (1.361.3) ...
```

So, essentially my bad from previous mucking around with my system.

Comment: Right, that explains the issue. Nice that you could find it yourself. This is exactly one of the reasons why people should not remove or replace the system's preinstalled Python instances.